# What is wrong in this final integer variable initialization?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I tried this code with lots of recorrections. But I could't found why it is illegal.Exlain what is wrong theoretically ?

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final int y;
        y=100;
        byte b;
        b=y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're asking why that code gives you

> Example.java:6: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
>
> ```
>    b=y;
>      ^
> ```

but this code doesn't:

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final int y=100; // <=======
        byte b;
        b=y;
    }
}
```

The reason is that if you don't provide the value as an initializer (you're assigning it later via assignment), the compiler doesn't treat it as a compile-time constant and so doesn't know that the value will fit in a `byte`. In part that's because to treat it as a compile-time constant, the compiler would have to handle the possibility you do this:

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final int y;
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            y=100;
        } else {
            y=1000;
        }
        byte b;
        b=y;
    }
}
```

So the compiler only handles `100` as a compile-time constant when it's an initializer, not when it's the value of an assignment.